# How to left join two tables in linq .net core 3.1

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1 project and I want to left join two tables. I've tried like the following:

```
 var mytotal = _context.Apiapplicant.Include(u => u.ApiApplicantHistory)
                       .Where(c => !c.ApiRequestDate.Equals("") 
                                   && c.IsDeleted.Equals(false))
                       .GroupBy(o => new
            {
                Month = o.ApiRequestDate.Substring(5, 2),
                Year = o.ApiRequestDate.Substring(0, 4),
                // Totallastreq = o.LastRequestStatus
            }).Select(g => new
            {
                Month = g.Key.Month,
                Year = g.Key.Year,
                // Totallastreq = g.Key.Totallastreq,
                Total = g.Count()
            }).ToList();


            var numerator =
                (from t1 in _context.VwReport
                 where t1.IsDeleted == false && t1.LastReqStatus == 15
                 let tg = new
                 {
                     Year = t1.ApiRequestDate.Substring(0, 4),
                     Month = t1.ApiRequestDate.Substring(5, 2),
                 }
                 group tg by new { tg.Year, tg.Month } into ApiAppGp
               
                 select new
                 {
                     Year = ApiAppGp.Key.Year,
                     Month = ApiAppGp.Key.Month,
                     //CountID = ApiAppGp.Count(i => i.apiID)
                     operationalAccessCount = ApiAppGp.Count()

                 }).ToList();

var leftJoinResult = (from t1 in mytotal
                  join t2 in numerator on new { t1.Month, t1.Year } equals 
                  new { t2.Month, t2.Year } into leftJoinGroup
                  from subset in leftJoinGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  
                  select new 
                  { 
                    Year = t1.Year, 
                    Month = t1.Month, 
                    percent = ((subset.operationalAccessCount*100) / t1.Total )
                  }).ToList();
```

My problem is, leftJoinResult returns null. I taced my code and I understood when t1.total has a value but the related value for subset.operationalAccessCount is null, my code stuck.I'm sure that my data are correct. I even changed percent like below:

```
percent = ((subset.operationalAccessCount.Equals(null) ? 0: 
                                      subset.operationalAccessCount*100
```

but it still it doesn't work.

I appreciate if anyone can suggest me a solution to solve it.

Comment: First, ASP.NET Core is a web framework, not an ORM. You're asking about EF Core. Second, you shouldn't have to use raw JOINs at all. Joins are generated by the ORM based on the entities and relations of your entities. If you try to use JOINs it means the entities are missing relations

Comment: I need to left join mytotal and numerator results. when I inner join them I get a result which is true but not my expected result which achieves just by left join them. So how can I do that?

Comment: Second, LINQ is *not* a replacement for SQL, it's a query language meant to be used on top of some other provider, in this case EF Core. It's *not* meant for writing complex reporting queries, like the one you try to write here. Your code is already very inefficient, as it loads all applicant and report data on the client before trying to join and calculate percentages on the *far weaker client machine*.

Comment: try the following `percent = subset?.operationalAccessCount == null ? 0 :  ((subset.operationalAccessCount*100) / t1.Total )` if `operationalAccessCount` nullable

Comment: @MinaMRM by moving the full reporting query back to the server, and rewriting it to avoid substring operations. You can speed up calendar aggregations immensely by creating a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) with eg 20 years of dates with recalculated year, month, week fields. Instead of a full table scan to retrieve date parts, you have a very fast join on the `date` columns and grouping on the (indexed) year and month columns

Comment: Dates aren't strings either, which means your database has more problems - either the dates are stored as strings, preventing efficient indexing, or your views/queries converted them to strings. In any case, those `Month = o.ApiRequestDate.Substring(5, 2)` will end up scanning the entire table to calculate the values

Comment: After your edit: so in the end this is just LINQ to objects. It should be simple to create a [mcve] that reproduces your issue.